# Laravel collection invalid ordering due AJAX request

Tags: jquery, json, laravel

When I try to sort Laravel collection by default `sort()` function - I got right ordering. But when I try to get this data via Ajax - I got invalid ordering from Ajax response.

For example:

```
 $a = collect([
         '2019-01-10', 
         '2019-01-01', 
         '2019-01-24', 
         '2019-01-03', 
         '2019-01-02'
        ])->sort();
```

Laravel `dd($a)` gaves me right ordering:

```
Collection {#508
  #items: array:5 [
    1 => "2019-01-01"
    4 => "2019-01-02"
    3 => "2019-01-03"
    0 => "2019-01-10"
    2 => "2019-01-24"
  ]
}
```

But when I tried return this data for jQuery Ajax request:

```
return response()->json([$a]);
```

`console.log()` of ajax response:

```
0: "2019-01-10"
1: "2019-01-01"
2: "2019-01-24"
3: "2019-01-03"
4: "2019-01-02"
```

Invalid ordering

**UPDATE**
I have more complicated data than an example:
At first, I got projects list:

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')
        ->whereIn(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')"), $dates)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Next I group by created_at:

```
$data = $projects->groupBy(function ($project) {
        return Carbon::parse($project->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
    })->sortKeysDesc(); //<----- sort to display newest first
```

so my result array sorting right and looks like:

```
[
'2019-01-20' => [...] nested arrays
'2019-01-15' => [...] nested arrays
'2019-01-10' => [...] nested arrays
]
```

But JS returns from Ajax:

```
 [
 '2019-01-10' => [...] nested arrays
 '2019-01-15' => [...] nested arrays
 '2019-01-20' => [...] nested arrays
 ]
```

Comment: a json abject does not assure the order, If you need the ordering on elements you need to use an array.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
$items = array_values($a->toArray());
return response()->json([$items]);
```

Comment: it works for the previous example, look at my update

Answer (score 1):

Use `->values()` to get rid of the array keys.

```
$a = collect([
         '2019-01-10', 
         '2019-01-01', 
         '2019-01-24', 
         '2019-01-03', 
         '2019-01-02'
        ])->sort()->values()
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure the order is preserved, you should use the build in `toArray()` function on collections.

```
return response()->json($a->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's make sure, that the problem is in the jQuery (or not). Try to execute same query with a Postman (or some other http client).